# how to chain CSS class selectors , which having multiple parent class?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors, chaining

## if HTML is like:

```
-section1
--h1
--h2
--h3
--section2
--h1
--h2
--h3
-section3
--h1
--h2
--h3
--section4
--h1
--h2
--h3
```

what should we do if we want to give **section1, section2, section3** same style and **section4** different style ? in short code.

I wrote the code like

```
.section1 .h1,
.section1 .h2,
.section1 .h3,
.section2 .h1,
.section2 .h2,
.section2 .h3,
.section3 .h1,
.section3 .h2,
.section3 .h3,{
     color: blue;
}
```

but its too long and looking bad, is there any short way to write this.

Comment: it has nothing to do with chaining. Rule of Thumb, declare the basic styles first and after that specific styles. means you use a selector that declares styles for the headlines in all sections and after that, you declare a specific design for the 4 sections overwriting the previous declared styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest vanilla CSS code is by selecting all elements that start with `section` by using the `[class^="..."]` attribute selector. Then overwrite the styles for section 4 specifically:

```css
[class^="section"] h1,
[class^="section"] h2,
[class^="section"] h3 {
  color: blue;
}

.section4 h1,
.section4 h2,
.section4 h3 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="section1">
  This is Section 1
  <h1>Headline 1</h1>
  <h2>Headline 2</h2>
  <h3>Headline 3</h3>
</section>
<section class="section2">
  This is Section 2
  <h1>Headline 1</h1>
  <h2>Headline 2</h2>
  <h3>Headline 3</h3>
</section>
<section class="section3">
  This is Section 3
  <h1>Headline 1</h1>
  <h2>Headline 2</h2>
  <h3>Headline 3</h3>
</section>
<section class="section4">
  This is Section 4
  <h1>Headline 1</h1>
  <h2>Headline 2</h2>
  <h3>Headline 3</h3>
</section>
```

Alternatively, you can also use a Preprocessor like SASS:

```scss
[class^="section"] {
  h1, h2, h3 {
    color: blue;
  }
}

.section4 {
  h1, h2, h3 {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below as well:

```css
[class^="section"]:not(.section4) :is(h1,h2,h3) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section class="section1">
  <h1>Headline 1</h1>
  <h2>Headline 2</h2>
  <h3>Headline 3</h3>
</section>
<section class="section2">
  <h1>Headline 1</h1>
  <h2>Headline 2</h2>
  <h3>Headline 3</h3>
</section>
<section class="section3">
  <h1>Headline 1</h1>
  <h2>Headline 2</h2>
  <h3>Headline 3</h3>
</section>
<section class="section4">
  <h1>Headline 1</h1>
  <h2>Headline 2</h2>
  <h3>Headline 3</h3>
</section>
```